# What permits us to compare the terms here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, polynomials, complex-numbers

If we had two polynomials $f$ and $g$ defined by $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_n x^n$ and $g(x) = b_0 + b_ 1 x + ... + b_n x^n$ and we knew $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$ we can start to compare the coefficients like $a_0 = b_0$ as we know  $a_i=b_i$. Moving on if we had $y + \sqrt{-2}$ we could suppose it can be written in the form $(a + b\sqrt{-2})^2$ and then expand out and compare the coefficients. Is the rule about "Two complex numbers that are equal will have same imaginary/real parts" the same rule that allows us to compare two identical polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a linear algebra thing. Both sets (complex numbers, polynomials) are vector spaces/modules with a basis. Two elements will be equal if and only if they have the same coordinates in that basis (any basis will work for this).

Comment: I didn't learn linear algebra yet so thanks!

Comment: @Mathguy This is one of the reasons why linear algebra comes first (before polynomials and rings of polynomials). On the other hand, two polynomials are equal iff the coefficients are are equal, by "pure definition", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528708/two-polynomials-r-1-r-2-in-rx-are-equal-if-and-only-if-the-cofficients-a?rq=1).

Comment: Is the complex number coefficients being equal also by definition?

Comment: @Dietrich Please be more careful with GB dupe closures.  The target you chose does not explain the second case in number fields, nor does it explain if they are "the same rule", so I have reopened it.

Comment: Bill you could perhaps answer this part of the question then we are done here?